# Manipulating Tree Structures for API endpoints

Tags: data-structures, api-design

I am working with an RDBMS that contains a list of hierarchical objects stored like this:

```
Id    Name                  ParentId
====================================
1     Food                  NULL
2     Drink                 NULL
3     Vegetables            1
4     Fruit                 1
5     Liquor                2
6     Carrots               3
7     Onions                3
8     Strawberries          4
...
999   Celery                3
```

I do not know the specific reason why this was chosen, but it is *fixed* in so far as the rest of the system relies on fetching the structure in this form.

I want to expose this data via **JSON** using a RESTful API, and I wish to output this in the following format (array of arrays):

```
item:
{
     id: 1, Description: "Food",
     items: [
         {
             id: 3, Description: "Vegetables",
             items: [ ... ]
         },
         {
             id: 4, Description: "Fruit",
             items: [ ... ]
         }
     ]
},
item:
{
    id: 2, Description: "Drink",
    items: [ ... ]
}
```

What would be a sensible way of looping through the data and producing the desired output? I'm developing in **C#** but if there are libraries or examples for other languages I would be happy to re-implement where possible.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: this..isn't a question..

Comment: Sorry, hit "Submit" by accident. Tabbed through the fields by accident when adding my code examples :/

Comment: Use Newtonsoft to serialize objects to JSON.

Comment: Can Newtonsoft change the nature of the relationship between parent and child elements in a tree?